# .Net/C# Google ML/Translation Exception: failed to connect to all addresses

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-platform

I am writing to you because i got error during using the AutoML API from google.cloud.
Documentation website:
https://cloud.google.com/translate/automl/docs/predict#automl_translate_predict-csharp

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadToTranslate(IFormFile excelFile)
{
    //rest of code...
    string credential_path = @"xxxx.json";
    System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", credential_path);
    var client = PredictionServiceClient.Create();
    var modelName = ModelName.Format(_config.GetValue<string>("ValuesEnPl:projectId"), _config.GetValue<string>("ValuesEnPl:location"), _config.GetValue<string>("ValuesEnPl:modelId"));
    var predictionRequest = new PredictRequest
    {
        Name = modelName,
        Payload = new ExamplePayload
        {
            TextSnippet = new TextSnippet
            {
                Content = "Tom goes home"
            },
        },
    };
    try
    {
        var response = client.Predict(predictionRequest, CallSettings.FromCallTiming(CallTiming.FromDeadline(DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(100))));
        foreach (var payload in response.Payload)
        {
            Console.Write($"Translated Content: {payload.Translation.TranslatedContent.Content}");
        }

    }
    catch (RpcException ex)
    {

    }
    //rest of code...
}
```

> Exception: Message = "Status(StatusCode=Unavailable, Detail=\"failed
>   to connect to all addresses\")"

Comment: You mentioned you used the one in [here](https://cloud.google.com/translate/automl/docs/predict#automl_translate_predict-csharp) but I can see that you change the way the credentials are defined, if you use the original way works fine?

Comment: Where is the exception being thrown? Currently you're swallowing all exceptions from calling `Predict`. Where is this code running? Are you behind a proxy that needs to be specified somewhere, for example?